# How to specify user roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a working login system, that required users to authenticate. The problem is I don't know how to connect the roles specified in the [Authorize] attribute to the roles specified in my database.

I hope someone can help me, because I don't really know where to start and can't find anything useful on the internet.

This is my accountcontroller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    IAuthProvider authProvider;
    public AccountController(IAuthProvider auth) {
        authProvider = auth;
    }

    public ViewResult Login() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]    
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (authProvider.Authenticate(model.Gebruikersnaam, model.Wachtwoord)) {
                return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));
            } else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Foute gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord");
                return View();
            }
        } else {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have my authorization set up like so:

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I made a custom AuthProvider:

```
public class FormsAuthProvider : IAuthProvider
{
    IUserRepository repository { get; set; }
    public FormsAuthProvider(IUserRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        bool result = false;
        IEnumerable<User> users = repository.GetAllUsers();

        if (users.Any(g => g.Username == username && g.Password == password)) {
            result = true;
        }
        if (result) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my user class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to use your custom tables for roles, you should implement a roles provider. You can do this by inheriting from abstract base class **System.Web.Security.RoleProvider** which lives in **System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll**. Once you inherit from **RoleProvider** you may be intimidated by all the methods automatically created. You will only have to provide implementations for methods you will be using (in your case I think it would be **GetRolesForUser**).

Once you implement the roles provider, register it with the framework using the **web.config**.

Have a look at the following article if you are new to the whole membership provider pattern.
http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/implementing-custom-membership-provider-and-role-provider-for-authinticating-aspnet-mvc-applications.aspx

Cheers